# The problem with calculating the amount for accounts Python

Tags: python, api, request

I am writing my bot in Python using the requests library. The essence of the bot is to calculate the total amount of all items on the account. Everything works fine, but the amount is not calculated as I need.

**API keys as dict:**

```
apikeys = {'account1' : [id1, apikey1], 'account2' : [id2, apikey2], 'account3' : [id3, apikey3]}
```

**My Code:**

```
total = 0
for key, value in apikeys.items():
    url = request.get('https://market.com/api/items?=key={api}'.format(api=value[1])).json()['items']
    for i in url:
        total += i['price']
```

**JSON Answer:**

```
ACCOUNT1 = {'items': [
           'item 1': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '10'
                     },
           'item 2': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '20'
                     },
           'item 3': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '30'
                     },  



ACCOUNT2 = {'items': [
           'item 1': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '40'
                     },
           'item 2': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '50'
                     },
           'item 3': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '60'
                     },



ACCOUNT3 = {'items': [
           'item 1': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '70'
                     },
           'item 2': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '80'
                     },
           'item 3': {
                     'status': '1',
                     'price': '90'
                     },
```

My bot collects all items from all accounts
**i got total = 450**
(*10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + 50 + 60 + 70 + 80 + 90* = **450**)

```
total = 450
```

But I need the amount to be separate for each account:

```
I need:

ACCOUNT1 = 10 + 20 + 30 = 60
ACCOUNT2 = 40 + 50 + 60 = 150
ACCOUNT3 = 70 + 80 + 90 = 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
account_total = {}
for key, value in apikeys.items():
    url = request.get('https://market.com/api/items?key={api}'.format(api=value[1])).json()['items']
    total = 0
    for i in url:
        total += i['price']
    account_total[key] = total
```

Comment: oh i sorry for last comment, it was my bad. Your answer is solut my problem. Thanks A LOT